# Redshift serverless - the account couldn't be created error message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I try to log in in a new AWS account to serverless Redshift - howerver I constantly get error that The account couldn't be created.

I followed the official steps from AWS Youtube channel - I left all settings as default and attached the account with IAM role that gas AmazonRedshiftAllCommandsFullAccess policy attached to it.

But when I go to Query data I got constantly this error

[image]

Any idea what I am missing here? Thank you in advance for any tips